# Função para gerar lançamento todo dia fixo

Tags: c#

Eu tenho esta função que quando começar com `T` ele vai gerar fatura para todo dia, exemplo: se tiver `T10` irá gerar todo dia 10 conforme especificado na forma de pagamento.
Atualmente está sendo feito desta forma:

```
  if (vf.Substring(0, 1) == "T")
                {
                    var par = vf.Substring(1, 2);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= parcelas; i++)
                    {
                        var venc = new FaturaContasReceber
                        {
                            FaturaContasReceberPId = idfatura,
                            DataFatura = DateTime.Now,
                            DiasAtraso = totalDia,
                            Data = DateTime.Parse(par + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")),
                            DataPagamento = datapagamento,
                            Valor = valor1,
                            Total = saldo,
                            Saldo = saldo,
                            Quitado = quitado,
                            Caixa = caixa,
                        };
                        db.Add(venc);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        saldo = 0;
                    }
                }
```

O problema que gerando hoje por exemplo, com todo dia 10, ele está gerando para o dia `10/05`, onde o correto seria para o dia `10/04`. Como posso fazer essa verificação de data ? Pois atualmente eu somo 1 mês

Utilizando a lógica de uma resposta adicionada a esta pergunta, fiz algumas mudanças e ficou desta forma:

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Day < Convert.ToInt32(par) && i == 1)
                        {
                            datavenc = DateTime.Parse(par + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            datavenc = DateTime.Parse(par + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 1).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                        }
```

Só que assim gera para o dia 10/04 e pula para o 10/06 e não 10/05.

Comment: Um comentário que não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas tem a ver com o código:
Se tivermos no mês 12 e tiver 2 parcelas, não ficaria "dd/12/2019" e "dd/01/2019", sendo que o correto seria "dd/01/2020"?

Comment: Referente a pergunta: Se trocar o `int i = 1` para `int i = 0`, provavelmente geraria no dia 10/04.

Comment: @Focos no caso se for todo dia, é todo próximo dia 10, caso seja outro tipo de condição ai deveria ser escolhido outra.

Comment: @Focos se eu começar no zero, em vez de gerar 2 vezes, geraria 3 vezes, por este motivo começa em 1.

Comment: Mas ai você coloca `i <= parcelas - 1`.

Comment: Ou simplesmente i < parcelas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudando um pouco seu código a lógica ficaria mais ou menos assim. Tem que melhorar o código mas a lógica é essa.

```
          DateTime teste = new DateTme();
          for (int i = 1; i <= parcelas; i++)
            {
                if(DateTime.Now.Day < Convert.ToInt32(par))
                {
                    teste = (par + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                }
                else
                {
                    teste = (par + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonth(1).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                }
                var venc = new FaturaContasReceber
                        {
                            FaturaContasReceberPId = idfatura,
                            DataFatura = DateTime.Now,
                            DiasAtraso = totalDia,
                            Data = teste,
                            DataPagamento = datapagamento,
                            Valor = valor1,
                            Total = saldo,
                            Saldo = saldo,
                            Quitado = quitado,
                            Caixa = caixa,
                        };
            }
```

Comment: Não funcionou, dessa forma gerou os dois para o mesmo mês. no caso de maio. continua para frente.

Comment: Erro meu, o sinal está invertido no if

Comment: Aproveitei um pouco da rua resposta, porém fiz dessa forma: `if (DateTime.Now.Day < Convert.ToInt32(par) && i == 1){
                                datavenc = DateTime.Parse(par + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                datavenc = DateTime.Parse(par + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 1).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                            }`